AWS Glue job written in pyspark not connecting with Postgresql using SSH tunneling
I have a PySpark AWS Glue job designed to extract data from an AWS RDS PostgreSQL database. To enhance security, our AWS RDS is configured as private, accessible only through a bastion host.
Our aim is to enable the Glue job to access the database using SSH tunneling. However, despite attempting to implement this feature, we're encountering a "Connection to localhost:37341 refused.Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." error.
Could someone kindly provide insights or suggestions on how we might accomplish this task successfully? Alternatively, are there alternative methods available for establishing connectivity between the AWS Glue job and the private database? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyodbc
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("App Name") \
    .getOrCreate()

try:
    server=SSHTunnelForwarder(('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',22),
      ssh_username='marketing',
      ssh_private_key="yourNewPrivateKey.pem",
      ssh_proxy_enabled=True,
      remote_bind_address=('localhost',3306)  
    )
    server.start()
    print('Server Started')
    
    df = spark.read \
      .format("jdbc") \
      .option("driver","org.postgresql.Driver") \
      .option("url","jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/yourDB") \
      .option("dbtable", "youtable") \
      .option("user", "youruserdatabase") \
      .option("password", "yourdatabasepassword") \
      .load()

except BaseException as e:
    print('Problem is -->', e)
finally:
    if server:
        server.close


1: Please post your actual code; the error message doesn't correspond to the ports in the code that you've posted. 2: This will only work if the read isn't distributed (I don't think it is, but can't be sure). 3: Glue lets you configure connections to in-VPC data sources; see the docs.
